# What's the right way to kill a process in Linux Kernel?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

What's the right way to kill a process in Linux Kernel, should I locate `sys_kill` and call it? (It looks rude)

P.S I have the `task_struct` and the pid of the target process

Comment: I would send SIGTERM to it.  to let it go done gracefully

Comment: @stdcall: That's not killing a process, it's sending it a signal which might have any number of effects. It may be what OP should be doing, but it's not what OP asked for, and it's not idiomatic for the kernel.

Comment: You could take a look at how the [OOM killer](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/oom_kill.c#L402) kills a process.

Comment: Generally you should avoid hacking your kernel and prefer user-land solutions.... **Why do you ask?**

Answer (score 3):

You can send the SIGKILL to the target process. thats a way to do it. But if there exists any userland solutions, i would never kill a process from kernel